# Adding href link in google sites through embedded code

Tags: html, google-sites-2016

There are three pages in my sites.google.com named (index.html, data.html, test.html). I created the three files using "Full Page Embed" option in Pages section. I am having issue with adding hyperlink of data.html inside index.html

I tried

`<a href="./data.html">Data</a>`

`<a href="data.html">Data</a>`

while trying the above ways, a link automatically adding up like https://2004xxxxxx-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com/embeds/16cb204cf3a9d4d2xxxxxxxxxxx/data.html and giving 404 error while accessing it.

I also used the direct link `<a href="https://sites.google.com/view/<path>/data-html">Data</a>` but many browsers blocking it, saying its external

Anyway to add hyperlink to the page inside the pages through embedded code itself

I am able to use `target="_blank"` which opening the links in new tabs but is there a way to show in the same tab (I used `target="_self"` but it blocking)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the blocking alert from the browsers when adding the direct link?

Comment: The question doesn't mention / use Google Apps Script

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Google is using frames that live in a completely different context for this full page embed feature.   Since that is the case, I think you need to use absolute URLs to link to the other pages on your site from that location:

```html
<a target=_top href="https://example.com/data.html">Data</a>
```

The `target=_top` makes the link apply to the whole window, not just in the frame.

Comment: Anyway to open it in the current tab? It's working for `target="_blank"` but not `target="_self"`

Comment: try `target=_top`

Comment: It's not working. I tried clicking on it multiple times, but it's not doing any action.

Comment: Can you share a link to it?